# How to get from Macau to Hong Kong airport for an early morning flight

Tags: airport-transfer, hong-kong, macau, hkg

There are direct ferries from Macau to the Hong Kong airport, but the last one leaves at 20:00 and the first one at 7:30. For a flight at 9 am or earlier I need a different way to get there. I like to avoid a night in Hong Kong or the airport itself. I also like to avoid taxis and I can't go through China. My flight is at 6:20 am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

I took the [3am ferry](http://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/routing-sailing-schedule/hong-kong-macau/sailing-schedule-fares.aspx) from Macau to Hong Kong Island.

[image]

Outside the ferry terminal I caught the [N11 bus](https://www.nwstbus.com.hk/en/uploadedFiles/cust_notice/RI-CTB-N11-N11-N.pdf) directly to the airport. It took about one hour and cost 31 HK$ (4 USD). It runs every 30 minutes, I took the 4:20am one. I was a bit concerned that 20 minutes may not be enough time to get from the ferry through immigration down to the bus, but at this time of the night it took less than ten minutes.

So there are enough ferries and buses all through the night to get you to the airport any time you need to.

This requires going through Hong Kong, so if you need a visa this may not be an option.

Comment: @pnuts - Oops, that would indeed be tight, I just checked and my flight was a 7:20 am, not 6:20. I had plenty of time.

Answer (score 4):

Turbojet has a ferry [almost every hour, all night](http://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/routing-sailing-schedule/hong-kong-macau/sailing-schedule-fares.aspx) from Macau to Hong Kong Ferry Terminal. From there you can take a short taxi ride (you could also walk but it's a bit far) to the Airport Express station and the train to the Airport. It will make your trip about an hour longer than going directly to the airport via ferry, but it sure beats staying at the airport over night.

Comment: I'd forget about the Airport Express that early morning: the [first train doesn't depart until 5:50am](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/services/timetable_index.html). By that time, you should probably be board(ing)(ed) already. When I researched this just over a month ago for a 6:30am flight of my own, I had to conclude you can't really get around a taxi for an early flight.

Comment: Note that this would mean entering Hong Kong though, which may not always be possible, depending on your nationality and/or lack of visas. The Macau-HKG boat drops you in the international bit of the airport without having to enter Hong Kong for immigration purposes

Answer (score 3):

One may get from Macau to Hong Kong  with the **24-hour bridge shuttle bus** via the [HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong%E2%80%93Zhuhai%E2%80%93Macau_Bridge), which takes about 30 minutes.

For more information, see [Hong Kong Airport – Macau – Hong Kong](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/148971/1810).