# Is there any Add Value Machine for Octopus at HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge) Hong Kong Port?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, hong-kong, macau

I am planning to go from Hong Kong to Macau via bus. I'll first go to [HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong%E2%80%93Zhuhai%E2%80%93Macau_Bridge) Hong Kong Port by bus, where I'll pass the immigration and buy a shuttle bus ticket to Macau with my Octopus card with the machine pictured below. Is there any Add Value Machine for Octopus at HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge) Hong Kong Port?

[image]

Example of Add Value Machine for Octopus:

[image]

Comment: These machines are in MTR stations only. But as the answer says, convenience stores provide recharge service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a convenience store in the HZMB (Hong Kong–Zhuhai–Macau Bridge) Hong Port where one can recharge an Octopus card via cash only (credit and debit cards are not accepted).

Convenience store information:
Circle K,  Boundary Crossing Facilities, Hong Kong, https://maps.app.goo.gl/g5coBRniHGRKT1DB7

It is located next to the machines to purchase shuttle bus tickets with an Octopus card (specifically, between the machines and the exit door where one has to go through to start queuing for shuttle buses after purchasing the tickets).

[image]