# Is there a way to go from Macau to Hong Kong by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, covid-19, hong-kong, macau

Under normal circumstances, to go from Macau to Hong Kong, you can use the [ferry](https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/routing-sailing-schedule/hong-kong-macau/sailing-schedule-fares.aspx) (not affiliated with that any company), the [bus](https://www.onebus.hk/en/) or even the helicopter

However :

[TurboJet](https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/routing-sailing-schedule/hong-kong-macau/sailing-schedule-fares.aspx) says :

> Important Notice:  In accordance with the HK Government announcement, effective from 00:00 am, 4 February 2020, Hong Kong Macau Ferry Terminal in Sheung Wan will be temporarily closed. Meanwhile, all the sailing services between HK and Macau will be suspended until further notice.

[ONEBUS](https://www.onebus.hk/en/) says (original emphasis)

> **One Bus have reached a decision that will suspend all services from 25th March 2020**

All companies seem to have taken the same steps and cancelled every mean of public transport between the two regions.

Outside of a 25h flight route, is there a way to go between the two regions using public transport?

Comment: It's only 9.5hrs via Beijing. Helpful chx is helpful.

Comment: FYI: [Hong Kong Airport – Macau – Hong Kong](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/148971/1810)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Through the Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macau bridge, [HZM bus](https://www.hzmbus.com/) (金巴) offers daily Hong Kong-Macau services. You will not pass through mainland Chinese immigration.

Online ticket purchase for Hong Kong -> Macau is not available. Seats are limited and you should ask the quarantine hotel in Macau for more information on the transport. You cannot book a ticket without a confirmation from the quarantine hotel anyway.

Macau -> Hong Kong is available to purchase online.

Of course, all quarantine, testing, vaccination and other public health and entry restrictions apply.